# Export components delphi xe2

Tags: delphi, export, components, delphi-xe2

I have a virtual machine with the delphi xe2 installed and expired, I would like to know how export all components used in my projects from this machine to other that has the delphi xe2 installed and activated.

I done it:
I copied the program folder into my new machine, also was exported the register from the virtual machine and installed. I copied the *.bpl files from the system32 folder to the other machine.

I imported a project from virtual machine that works normally, and in my new machine occur many problems with components not found.

How can I solve this?

Notes: I have only this project in this virtual machine, I bought it.
I dont have many knowledges in Delphi. I am starting. I'm a Java Developer.

Thanks

Comment: What you're trying to do is illegal, if you're referring to the Delphi components.

Comment: Perhaps you should be seeking understanding rather than a recipe here.

Comment: I think that I am not sure of which components i need to import. :(. I only want open this project in other machine, But it sounds like impossible, without I to know all componentes used.

Comment: once you will try open project or specific form, or once you will try to compile project you will start receiving error.... collect all information about error, mostly it will be because you have missing components. after that will be much easy to find required components. good luck!

Comment: I can't imagine working on a project without knowing what libraries it uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Come to think of it: what is expired? If Delphi XE2 is expired, it is probably a **trial** version (which is usually an Architect SKU). **You can not copy its components and use them**. They will not work in a normal environment. Otherwise, someone could buy the much cheaper Professional and simply copy everything from the (Architect) trial version over to their Professional install and use them. The trial components are not compatible with anything but the trial of the same version.

If you mean *third party components*: usually, these components are installed with an installer. Copy these installers to your other installation and install them like before.

That is perhaps a bit slower, but the only proper way to do this. Anything else means fuddling with the registry and perhaps .ini files and what not, and a lot of frustration etc. The installers know what to install and how.

Your project sources can simply be copied over as they are, i.e. copy the entire directories. But **first** install all necessary components. If you used components from a trial version, and your XE2 doesn't have them, you must abandon them.

Comment: "perhaps a bit slower" Actually no, it's much slower to try to figure out the wrong way to do it :P

Answer (score 0):

1. try 3rd party tools calling CnPack Wizard for copy configuration.
2. mostly BPL's are located in `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\Bpl` where 15.0 -- Delphi version number (15.0 is XE7)